# Browser window callback on iOS

Tags: ios, callback, mobile-safari

I would like to pass data from an iOS browser window back to the app.  What would be the mechanism for doing so?  As in, the user would click "Submit" on an HTML button in the browser, and there would be some data passed from the browser window back to the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is typically done using JavaScript.

[Here's an article describing the process of linking JS and Swift.](https://medium.com/john-lewis-software-engineering/ios-wkwebview-communication-using-javascript-and-swift-ee077e0127eb)